# Connect to SalesForce Marketing Cloud in Talend

Tags: talend

I am using the Talend Open Studio 8. I am working on to extract the Data extensions data from  Salesforce cloud Platform

I know the use which I have is a rarely preferable architecture , however , I would like to check ,how the talend can be connect to salesforce marketing cloud and extarct data directly from data extensions.

Is there any component like tsalesforceInput available in talend to connect salesforce marketing cloud

Comment: I assume you’ve read the Talend documentation so what precise issues are you facing?